# Input text won't properly display on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a game using the tKinter library in Python. I have made three functions that kind of have to work together. Two functions serve the purpose of showing a name input and saving it into a variable, while the other function serves as the game itself. The first listed function is what I use to store the input into variables. The second function is for the name input. The third function is for the game itself.

```
def input_ophalen():
    input = Naam1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(input)
    input = Naam2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(input)
    input = Naam3.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(input)

def create_kiezen():
    global Naam1
    global Naam2
    global Naam3

    kiezen = Tk()
    kiezen.geometry('600x600')
    kiezen.title('Namen invoeren!')
    kiezen.configure(background='darkgrey')
    Spelen = Button(kiezen, text='Begin!', bd='5', height='2', width='15',
                    command=lambda: [kiezen.destroy(), Spelmenu()])
    Terug = Button(kiezen, text='Terug', bd='5', height='2', width='15', command=lambda: [kiezen.destroy(), menu()])
    Spelen.pack(anchor='s', side='right')
    Terug.pack(anchor='s', side='left')
    kiezen.minsize(400, 400)
    kiezen.maxsize(400, 400)

    naamblok = Canvas(kiezen, width=300, height=200)
    naamblok.place(x=50, y=50)
    Opslaan=Button(naamblok, height=1, width=10, text='Opslaan', command=lambda: input_ophalen())
    Opslaan.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)

    Naam1=Text(naamblok, width=15, height=1)
    Naam1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
    Naam2= Text(naamblok, width=15, height=1)
    Naam2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)
    Naam3=Text(naamblok, width=15, height=1)
    Naam3.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    mainloop()

def Spelmenu():
    global punt1
    global punt2
    global punt3

    spelmenu = Tk()
    spelmenu.geometry('400x400')
    spelmenu.title('Spelen maar!')
    spelmenu.configure(background='darkgrey')
    spelmenu.minsize(400, 400)
    spelmenu.maxsize(400, 400)
    volgendeB = Button(spelmenu, text='Volgende worp', bd='5', height='2', width='15')
    volgendeB.place(x=150, y=350)

    wBeurt = Canvas(spelmenu, width=300, height=60)
    wBeurt.place(x=50, y=40)
    wBeurt.create_text(150, 30, text="De beurt is aan " + str(Naam1))

    scores = Canvas(spelmenu, width=300, height=200)
    scores.place(x=50, y=130)
    worp1=randint(1,6)
    worp2=randint(1,6)
    fWorp1=str(worp1)
    fWorp2=str(worp2)

    if worp1 < worp2 or worp1 > worp2:
        punt1 = 2
        scores.create_text(156, 10, text="Je hebt " + fWorp1 + " en " + fWorp2 + " gegooit dus je hebt 2 punten gekregen!")
    else:
        punt1 = 5
        scores.create_text(156, 10, text="Je hebt " + fWorp1 + " en " + fWorp2 + " gegooit dus je hebt 5 punten gekregen!")

    mainloop()
```

The problem with the code is that whenever you get to the actual window for the game, it shows the following in the top canvas: "De beurt is aan .!canvas.!text". Instead of ".!canvas.!text" I want there to be the name of the first player. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Change `w.Beurt.create_text(... + str(Naam1))` to `w.Beurt.create_text(... + Naam1.get("1.0", "end-1c"))`.

Comment: For single line input, better use `Entry` instead of `Text` with `height=1`.

Comment: When I change it to that I get the following error: `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas.!text"`

Comment: Did you call `create_keizen()` before `Spelmenu()`? Otherwise `Naam1` is not created.

Comment: I called create_kiezen() before i called Spelmenu(). I have also changed the `Text` to `Entry`, but this also does not work.

Comment: Just notice that you call `keizen.destroy()` before calling `Spelmenu()`.  Since `Naam1` is created inside `keizen`, so it will be destroyed as well.  That is why you get the error.

Comment: To avoid that i would lose the variable i used the `global` statement at the top of my create_kiezen() function. Doesn't that enable the variables to be used outside the function? If you're referring to the button with the lambda commands: If i switch calling kiezen.destroy() and Spelmenu() it won't close the create_kiezen's window

Answer (score 0):

Since `keizen.destroy()` is called before `Spelmenu()`, `Naam1` will be destroyed as well.  So exception will be raised when `Naam1` is accessed inside `Spelmenu()`.

Suggest to use another global `StringVar` `Naam1_var` to store the content of `Naam1` and use that variable inside `Spelmenu()`:

```py
def create_kiezen():
    global Naam1, Naam1_var
    ...
    Naam1_var = StringVar()
    Spelen = Button(kiezen, text='Begin!', bd='5', height='2', width='15',
                    command=lambda: [Naam1_var.set(Naam1.get("1.0", "end-1c")), kiezen.destroy(), Spelmenu()])
    ...

def Spelmenu():
    ...
    wBeurt.create_text(150, 30, text="De beurt is aan " + Naam1_var.get())
    ...
```

Comment: I tweaked the code with the suggestions that you gave and now it works like how I want it to work! Thank you so much for this solution!